# php : Array to string conversion. How to solve this?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I am going to separate an array's elements with `,` but I have a error

`Array to string conversion`

My php codes:

```
// get sliders from database
$all_slider = $this->db_submit_product->get_slider($shoe_ID);
$data['my_slider'] = array();

foreach ($all_slider as $row) {
    array_push($data['my_slider'], $row->pic);
}

// Use $data['my_slider']
$filename_arr[] = $data['my_slider'];
$file_coma = implode(',', $filename_arr);
// line of error is about last line
```

What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't you imploding `$data['my_slider']` instead?

Comment: Put your error into Stack search, or Google "Array to string conversion" - what happens? ;) It sometimes (usually) takes less time to search an error and read the results than it does asking a question.

Comment: why do you have brackets after $filename_arr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the brackets from the variable filename_arr.

```
// Use $data['my_slider']
$filename_arr = $data['my_slider'];
$file_coma = implode(',', $filename_arr);
```

Comment: that would be the same as just replacing $filename_arr with $data["my_slider"]...

Comment: Yes of course, but it's more didactic to highlight the faulty variable declaration.@MadsBjaerge

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have all sorts of unnecessary code in your example and you dont seem to understand arrays very well.

```
$all_slider = $this->db_submit_product->get_slider($shoe_ID);
$pic_list = array();

foreach ($all_slider as $row) {
    $pic_list[] = $row->pic;
}

$file_coma = implode(',', $pic_list);

// put the pic_list array into $data for the View.
$data = array();
$data['slider'] = $pic_list;
```

The variable `$file_coma` should now contain a comma seperated list of whatever was in `$row->pic`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I need $data['slider'] to pass into view. There was just a mistake That was solved in first answer. I don't know why I got 4 negetive! Any way, Thanks :)

Comment: @vahidnajafi "don't know why I got 4 negative" because Stack and the entire internet would have told you what your issue is had you bothered to even try searching first. Sorry to be blunt, but this question is pointless. It was even a waste of your time, as you could have found your answer quicker by searching.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the code so it now adds the array of pics into a variable called `$data['slider']` for your view.

Comment: @vahidnajafi No need for apology, was just giving advice.

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = ['first'=>'One','sec'=>'Two','third'=>Three];
echo implode(' ',$data);
```

The output is

```
One Two Three
```